# Best way to run rsync as a LaunchDaemon from an osx 10.6.8 machine to back up data to an Ubuntu 11.1 server

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rsync

I am running rsync as a LaunchDaemon from an osx 10.6.8 workstation to back up data to an Ubuntu 11.1 server. Since I am putting my plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons, it runs as root. Unfortunately, it fails because the command requires the root password of the server. When I run it using myself as a user, rsync uses the ssh key I've set up between the two machines for my account but unfortunately, it fails building a full file list on my osX machine because I do not have the permissions to list other user's directories.

I can see a couple of possibilities, neither of which I know how to do:

-1- On osx, how can I give myself the permissions to list other users' directories so I can run the daemon under my own user name?
OR
-2- If I run the rsync daemon as root, can I set up ssh keys between the root accounts of both machines in a safe way? Alternatively, can I automatically feed the password to the deamon job in a relatively safe way?

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy possibilities for using your key under the root account:

1. Copy your ssh key into the root account's ssh directory (/var/root/.ssh).
2. Specify your ssh key explicitly in the ssh command, something like this:

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
       <string>/usr/bin/rsync</string>
       <string>-i</string>
       <string>/Users/thomashollier/.ssh/id_rsa</string>
       <string>...etc...</string>
   <array>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. I copied my key over to the server's proper location for the root ssh key. I was able to ssh and rsync from my osX machine to the server on the command line but not directly from my launchDaemon. The rsync command on the command line required the -e "ssh -i /path/to/my/key/id_dsa" argument and I haven't figured out how to include these quotes in the plist file other than feeding it a bash command as follows:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/usr/bin/rsync -avz /Users/myusername/Documents -e "ssh -i /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa" server:/media/Backup/backup/</string>
</array>
```